# Getting the correct SHA-256 hash of a 128 bit binary string in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, binary, cryptography, sha256

I’m trying to get the correct SHA-256 hash of a 128 bit binary string in PHP. Below is an example of a correct hash which was calculated at https://cryptii.com/hash-function:

---

**Binary String:** 00110001110010011100000110100111101100100111110011010100011010001000011111110111101000001111111011100011101100110101111101001011

**SHA-256:** eab9eee82d6427d3544129f43796a98b82455f28ec921083c23524757bdead91

---

I have the binary string stored in a text file which is read with:

```
// $binstring='00110001110010011100000110100111101100100111110011010100011010001000011111110111101000001111111011100011101100110101111101001011';
$binstring = file_get_contents('bin.txt');
$sha256 = hash('sha256', $binstring);
echo $sha256;
// Result:6112fa0eb3c8b8bbff62f2c85bf0aee09655d8f1d51f8a6b038dd5661e573f96
```

The above code results in the *incorrect* SHA-256 hash value shown. I suppose this is because the hash function is generating the SHA-256 from the string and not from the actual binary.

I’ve attempted some different methods of passing the binary to the hash function but think I’m being limited by the max integer when treating the binary as anything other than a string.

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround to the above? I know PHP probably isn’t the best way of achieving this but I’d like to see if it is possible before looking at other solutions.

I’ve put a couple of additional examples of correct binary to SHA-256 hashes below for reference, these were also generated with the cryptii.com link above:

---

**Binary String:** 11001010101010001101001001100110011000000001001100000111101011001101111100000100100010111011110100010001010100000100000100101111

**SHA-256:** 9d6e178ab78d35647b916fd6d8988607cb4092338c0266c40ea2af70ef9c378a

---

**Binary String:** 01100011100110010011000001001010110000010110111100001010100101100111011000011011010111100011101100101111000101101010001000100101

**SHA-256:** 11024115219275eee8960fc1cd7b876842c162abc078fbbc92f5dd9e7b65a3a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP, as far as I can tell, doesn’t seem to have any built in way to convert a string of `1` and `0` into the raw bytes, so you need to do it yourself.

Here’s one possible way, reading eight characters at a time in a loop (i.e. for each byte) and converting into a character to build up the string.

```
$binstring = '00110001110010011100000110100111101100100111110011010100011010001000011111110111101000001111111011100011101100110101111101001011';

$data = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($binstring); $i += 8) {
    $next = substr($binstring, $i, 8);
    $next = chr(bindec($next));

    $data .= $next;
}


$sha256 = hash('sha256', $data);
echo $sha256;

// Result: eab9eee82d6427d3544129f43796a98b82455f28ec921083c23524757bdead91
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and keeps everything in PHP saving a potential headache. Very elegant solution.